# What is more efficient? Updating million records at once using oracle update queries or using PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bulkupdate

I want to update 8 Million records in a Oracle table with specific values from an excel sheet.
Is it efficient to run 8 million update queries at once, or is it better to use a PL SQL script for the same?

If PL SQL is a better option, how can I achieve it? Since I will need to store the the values TO BE updated and the values TO WHICH they should be updated in some data structure like a hashmap and then run a for loop on it. But is it feasible to hard code 8 million values in a PL SQL data structure?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table(s); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that demonstrates the issue; examples of an SQL `UPDATE` and a PL/SQL statement that you want to compare.

Comment: As a general rule, "set" operations like `UPDATE` or `MERGE` that process sets of rows at once are faster by orders of magnitude over any programmatic for/next loop or individual row-by-row processing.

Comment: PL/SQL has no direct interaction with the data, it uses SQL engine to perform operations on database tables. It also doesn't have native parallelisation, all the statements are executed sequentially as they were written. So it doesn't add any magic to speed up a plain update. The main issue here is to transfer 8 million rows from Excel file to the database side since Excel doesn't allow to open a file in a streaming mode. Once you've opened it you may use batch update via .Net capabilities (from the Powershell or VBA) or save it to the CSV, upload the data via SQLLoader and perform `merge`

Answer (score 0):

One option might be

- load data from Excel file (I presume it contains at least `old_value` and `new_value`) into the database

  - alternatively, save it as a CSV file and create an **external table** on it
- once data is in the database, write update (or merge), such as

  ```
  update target_table a
    set a.column_value = (select b.new_value 
                          from loaded_table b
                          where b.old_value = a.column_value
                         )
  where exists (select null
                from loaded_table c
                where c.old_value = a.column_value
               );
  ```

  Don't forget to properly index both tables!

---

If you do it in PL/SQL (I presume you mean to use a loop?), then it'll probably be quite slow as you'll process row-by-row.